# SGE grid job dependency

Tags: linux, sungridengine

I have a dilemma of streamlining a sequence of SGE grid jobs that have some dependency among them but haven't figured out a correct way of specifying `-hold_jid`.

Suppose we have jobs like:

```
job1: qsub -N job1 ... 
job2: qsub -N job2 -hold_jid job1
job3: qsub -N job3 -hold_jid job2
```

then the order of execution is guaranteed to be job1->job2->job3.

However, suppose within the complicated job2, there is an embedded SGE job, say job2a:

```
job2a: qsub -N job2a.${timestamp_of_submission}
```

In this case, I haven't figured out a way to make sure job3 run after job2a completes.

attempt1:

```
qsub -N job3 -hold_jid job2 ...
```

Then surely job3 waits until job2 finishes, however, there is no guarantee that job3 will be executed after job2a, which is what i wanted.

attempt2:

```
qsub -N job3 -hold_jid job2a* ...
```

then job3 seems to be executed right away since job2a isn't shown in the job array until job2 starts to run. Note I used `*` above to avoid specifying the exact name of job2a, because the timestamp of submission is hard to guess beforehand.

Anyone knows a way to achieve the dependency chain as job1->job2->job2a->job3?
Thanks!

Comment: The dependency is determined at submission time, so if job3 is submitted before job2a... this will be challenging. It should be possible to use qalter (possibly within job2 or whatever is creating job2a) to change the dependency as needed. http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman1/qsub.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving `-hold_jid` a list of job Id:

```
qsub -N job2
qsub -N job2a
qsub -N job3 -hold_jid job2,job2a.${timestamp_of_submission}
```

Alternatively, capturing the job Id should also work:

```
job2a=$(qsub -N job2a.${timestamp_of_submission} | perl -p -e "s/Your job (\d+) .*/\1/g;")
qsub -N job3 -hold_jid job2,${job2a}
```

**EDIT**

Based on comment, you need to get list of job id.

So I would suggest the following:

```
job2list=$(qsub -N job2 | perl -p -e "s/Your job (\d+) .*/\1/g;")
```

The above stores the job id for job 2.

Then every time you submit a job2a-type job do:

```
job2a=$(qsub -N job2a.${timestamp_of_submission} | perl -p -e "s/Your job (\d+) .*/\1/g;")
job2list="${job2list},${job2a}"
```

The above will append job2a job id to the id for job2.

When ready to submit job 3 do:

```
qsub -N job3 -hold_jid ${job2list}
```

Comment: thanks but this didn't work for me: in my case, i tried -hold_jid job2,job2a* because indeed there are multiple sub-jobs for job2a, all with the same prefix 'job2a'. At runtime, job3 did wait for job2 to finish, but didn't wait for any of the job2a* jobs to complete.

Comment: To clarify, did you add all the job2a job id to the `-hold_jid` option, or did you use wildcard (`*`)?

Comment: I used wildcard because it's not possible to enumerate all of the job names on the fly, i.e., the list of timestamps of submission

Comment: to avoid the perl command, the jobid can be obtained by using the `-terse` argument in `qsub`